# Sort and remove duplicates in a string in C

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I have a problem with "creating" a code, I just started the college and I need help with this problem: make a C program where you sort and remove duplicate words in a string.

E.g.:

**input:** potato potato apple orange strawberry orange

**output:** apple orange potato strawberry

This is what I got into so far, it only sorts, but doesn't remove the duplicates:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  int i, j, k, space = 0;
  char str[100], words[50][100], cmp[50];

  printf("Enter the string  \n");
  scanf(" %[^\n]s", str);
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
  {
    if ((str[i] == ' ')||(str[i] == ', ')||(str[i] == '.'))
      space++;
  }
  for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;j < strlen(str);j++)
  {
    if ((str[j] == ' ')||(str[j] == 44)||(str[j] == 46))
    {
      words[i][k] = '\0';
      i++;
      k = 0;
    }else
      words[i][k++] = str[j];
  }

  for (i = 0;i < space;i++) //loop for sorting
  {
    for (j = i + 1;j <= space;j++)
    {
      if ((strcmp(words[i], words[j]) > 0))  //swapping strings
      {
        strcpy(cmp, words[i]);
        strcpy(words[i], words[j]);
        strcpy(words[j], cmp);
      }
    }
  }
  printf("After sorting string is \n");
  for (i = 0;i <= space;i++)
    printf("%s ", words[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

I still haven't learn about pointers or functions and can't use them to do this code.

Thank you,
Amorim.

Comment: If you've already gotten a sorted list of words, all you have to do is go through it and ignore or remove any words that are the same as the previous one.

Comment: Dmtri, but I do that inside a "for"? I have no idea

Comment: If the word isn't the first one (`i` is non-zero), check if it's the same as the previous (`strcmp(words[i], words[i-1])` returns 0) and if so, ignore it.

Comment: Yeah.. still don't get where to put things, do you recommend any book or website to "understand algorithms"?

Comment: 'but I do that inside a "for" what?   If you don't know that, how did you write the rest of it?

Comment: Thingy, I got help from a friend that is in the same class as I, he tried to explain to me but I don't quite get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
  int i, j = 0, k, l, n, space = 0,pos;
  char str[100], words[50][100], cmp[50];

  printf("Enter the string  \n");
  scanf(" %[^\n]s", str);
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
  {
    if ((str[i] == ' ')||(str[i] == ', ')||(str[i] == '.'))
      space++;
  }
  for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;j < strlen(str);j++)
  {
    if ((str[j] == ' ')||(str[j] == 44)||(str[j] == 46))
    {
      words[i][k] = '\0';
      i++;
      k = 0;
    }else
      words[i][k++] = str[j];
  }

  for (i = 0;i < space;i++) //loop for sorting
  {
    for (j = i + 1;j <= space;j++)
    {
      if ((strcmp(words[i], words[j]) > 0))  //swapping strings
      {
        strcpy(cmp, words[i]);
        strcpy(words[i], words[j]);
        strcpy(words[j], cmp);
      }
    }
  }
  printf("After sorting string is \n");
  for (i = 0;i <= space;i++)
    printf("%s ", words[i]);

  for (i = 0;i < space;i++) //loop for removing duplicate word
  {
      if ((strcmp(words[i], words[i+1]) == 0))  // finding duplicate word
      {
        pos=i+1; //Store the location of duplicate word
        for (j = pos;j < space;j++) //loop for deleting duplicate
          {
        strcpy(words[j], words[j+1]);
      }
         space--;
         i--;
    }
  }
  printf("\n After deleting duplicate string is \n");
  for (i = 0;i <= space;i++)
    printf("%s ", words[i]);  

  return 0;
}
```

This will remove any duplicate words in your input string.

Comment: I misstyped, see if you can click the link now

Comment: If I changed to **gets**, would be better? Would remove some lines that are unnecessary

Comment: [NEVER use gets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks with the GCC compiler

Comment: [check it](https://ibb.co/issF1Q).Check the image and verify if i say wrong

Comment: It worked, but now I read the "problem" that the teacher sent, it's different, you need to ask how many words there will be and then type them.

Comment: "Make a program that creates a vector of n words, n being a size entered by the user(maximum 100). Your program should remove all the repeated words and sort the words.
Print the final vector without repeated and ordered words."

Comment: I don't quite get the way it will be, if the words will be separated by "space" or "enter", like "enter word 1: **word**"

Comment: Put up new question giving the above question and the code you just have.It would help you.

Comment: My pleasure i will try to resolve tye problem in mean yime